# Track custom events on GA inserted by GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I have inserted Google Analytics using Google Tag Manager on my site.

Often, an site has only one analytics. But when you have multiple, analytics recommends to name them.

Custom Events using `ga("send", "...")` only apply to the global analytics instance. I need to track an Ajax Form with custom events. If you have a named instance, you need to call `ga("INSTANCE_NAME.send", "...")`.

The problem: Tag Manager is inserting the analytics with an name (`gtm1`) even having only one instance. This way, i need always to set the name on custom events and on my case, i can't do it because i use an plugin.

What i need is to remove the name inserted by tag manager and use an global instance, but i want to keep using the tag manager to insert the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the advanced settings there is a field where you can override the tracker name (if you use a settings variable you need to check "enable override settings" first). I haven't done this for some time, but it used to be that if you enabled the field but did not enter a name the tracker name would revert to the default.

[image: override settings variable]

[image]

Comment: Sorry but i still didn't find this field. I am inserting an Universal Analytics. Didn't find the field that overrides the name.

Comment: Added some screenshots.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. Would be nice to get rid of this name by default.